# test command says that the function is not defined

Tags: go

I have written a test file named "deck_test.go"
the contents are

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestNewDeck(t *testing.T) {
    d := newDeck()

    if len(d) != 2000 {
        t.Errorf("Expected deck length of 20 , but got %v", len(d))
    }
}
```

The function `newDeck()` is defined in other file of the `main` package.
But when I run `go test -v deck_test.go` it outputs:

```
go test -v deck_test.go 
# command-line-arguments [command-line-arguments.test]
./deck_test.go:6:7: undefined: newDeck
FAIL    command-line-arguments [build failed]
FAIL
```

Also, I see that the build failed in the result.

For reference here is my `go env` output

```
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/apm/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/apm/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/apm/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/apm/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.17.1"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/apm/go/cards/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build1111912483=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

Can anyone explain what is the issue here?

EDIT_01:
As suggested in the comments, I did a test omitting the file name.
And below is the result
[image]
There is still something strange because, this test I have written to fail. I feel some path or something is set wrong and the test is being ran at some other directory.

EDIT_02: Also the function which I am testing looks like this:

```
type deck []string    
func newDeck() deck {
    cards := deck{}

    cardSuits := []string{"Spades", "diamonds", "hearts", "clubs"}
    cardValues := []string{"Ace", "two", "three", "four"}

    for _, suit := range cardSuits {
        for _, value := range cardValues {
            cards = append(cards, value+"of"+suit)
        }
    }
    return cards
}
```

Can anyone have a look?

Comment: `go test -v deck_test.go` compiles only the file that you have supplied, i.e. only `deck_test.go` is compiled. Omit the file so that the whole package is compiled, i.e. use `go test -v`. For more details on the command read: [Test packages](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Test_packages).

Comment: @mkopriva Can you please see the EDIT section which i added now after trying the way you told?

Comment: `go test` runs the tests in the current directory, if that's not where your code is then that's the problem, if that *is* where you code is then, if the test isn't behaving as you expect, the problem is with the implementation of the function under test, which you have omitted from the question. Nobody can tell you why `TestNewDeck` is not FAILing without seeing the function it is testing, i.e. without seeing `newDeck()`.

Comment: @mkopriva I have added the function which I was to test in EDIT_02. I am pretty sure that there is nothing wrong with the function though :) May be I am missing something.

Comment: The function looks normal & and the test should fail, however... The returned deck has length of 16, not 20 as the error message in the test states which means that the code snippets are just "out of sync" or that one or both are not the actual code you are executing... And what is causing the "root" print in the stdout? For debugging you can add print statements into the test function, for example one that prints the length of `d` outside of any if statement to check the length is what you expect and to check that the test func is even running.

Comment: Simply the code you provided and the behaviour you described do not match. If you want help you have to provide a [mcve]. See this [screenshot](https://imgur.com/XOsLkTN), the given code works as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing it.
As @Kelsnare commented out to this answer, the right way of doing this is to pull the code out of my original go path (which was `/home/apm/go`) and putting it into another folder.
Then I changed my GOPATH to the older one `/home/apm/go` by using `env GOPATH="/home/apm/go"`

Then I `cd` into the new work folder and ran
`go mod init`
and also
`go mod tidy`

After this I ran `go test -v` and got the correct output.

Comment: That is not the proper use of GOPATH. And GOPATH shouldn't prevent `go test` from running tests in the current directory. If your go installation is not working as advertised it is likely due to misconfiguration and you should probably uninstall and then re-install. But install it using the official channels rather than whatever path you took previously.

Comment: Using [modules](https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules) might alleviate these problems for you. Revert your `GOPATH` back to `/home/amp/go`. Pull your code folder, `cards`, out of `GOPATH` and put it literally anywhere else. `cd` into it. run `go mod init cards`. then run `go mod tidy`. and finally `go test -v`.